# Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I try to connect to my FTP, but I get this error and can't see my files. I run a **Debian 8** server and use **VSFTPD** for FTP.

my vsftpd.conf has the following line:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Transfer mode in Filezilla is active.

This is the error I get in filezilla:

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to {ip}:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PORT 10,206,61,154,216,42
Response:   500 Illegal PORT command.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode ({ip},242,183).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Error:  GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

This is what I get in my VSFTPD log:

```
Fri May 12 12:09:48 2017 [pid 17474] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:194.104.70.4"
Fri May 12 12:09:48 2017 [pid 17473] [allviddie] OK LOGIN: Client "::ffff:194.1$
```